# Would 'Wedding Assets' be understood as I expect?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I looking for a category type of expression to group all those extra services and people you could book for a wedding – but I fear it's understood differently. So the term I would want to use would be "assets" – so in my understanding an "asset" could be a photographer, a clown, a band etc.

Doing a little research on the matter I got the impression that "assets" is instead actually used for stocks and bank accounts. Now I'm a bit worried, if it would be understood if I tried to use the term "assets" anyways? Or would there be a different, more suitable term for this…?

Thank you!

Comment: Assets can frequently be used more figuratively beyond financial investments, however it would be more common to use to refer to an attribute, rather than an option.  For example . you might compare relative assets to a location : good freeway access,  views, weather ... but less comfortably to refer to "large dance floor", 'cocatail deck' as an asset -- that might be more comfortably referred to as 'features' or "ammenities".  As for a menu of possible services for a wedding "options" or "services" would be better, atlhough "featured options" or "wedding extras" or "enhancements" ?

Comment: 'Wedding assets' sounds to me like a term lawyer's might use in composing a pre-nuptial agreement.

Comment: My first thought was something that may, or may not, still be possessed by the prospective bride.

Comment: 'Wedding assets' sounds perilously close to the BrE slang expression 'wedding tackle'.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all people you could describe them collectively as service providers, or perhaps contractors.